# Set session value in jquery and get same value in php

Tags: php, jquery

How to **Set** session value in jQuery and **Get** that value in PHP? We have to set some value in session in jQuery and get the same session values in PHP

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url+"api/v1.0/ssoauthentication/submitOtp",
    type: "POST",
    datatype : "json",
    data:'phone_number='+phone_number+'&country_code='+country_code+'&otp='+otp+'&device_type=1&device_token=sasasa&device_id=3',
    success:function(data){

        var data  = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
        if(data.status == false){
            $('#loader').removeAttr("class")
            $.each(data.data, function(key, value){
                $('#'+key+'_error').html(value);
            })
            //find common error
            if( typeof data.message != "undefined"){
                var value = data.message;
                $('#common_error').html(value);
            }

        }else{
            alert(data.data['new_otp']);
            //opt is need to save in session and i get otp new page in seesion 
            window.location = base_url+'web/view_sso_authentication/';

        }
```

Comment: I have called php file using ajax. that file to return some values. i need that values in next page. i get the value in session

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: pass as get parameter

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is. Please take some time to read [ask]

Comment: Sure Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookie instead of session in jQuery/javascript. I'm not sure about sessions that created through javascript are accessible in php or not. But cookies are.

To create cookie in javascript:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 27 July 2017 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

In above code 'username' is cookie name while 'John Doe' is the value of cookie. 
'expires' is the expiration time which is '27 July 2017' you can set any date you want. and path tells that where you can access this cookie.

To get cookie value in php use below code:

```
$user_cookie = $_COOKIE['username'];
```

Now we get our cookie value in 'user_cookie' variable.

Remember to use `session_start()` in php.

If you still want to use session: Refer to [this plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin). I'm not sure $_SESSION variable will access your session or not in php because I have not tested but I listen from several developers they are using this plugin.

Comment: Makes no sense setting that cookie in javascript since it can be set at server. Also don't see why OP needs to use a cookie when next page also has access to the session

Comment: He want to request to ajax page and want to hide something from user. Therefore he can do this. Be cool. If javascript cookie has no benefit why developers created it?